# expressjs node.js serve different data to google/etc bot and human traffic

Tags: javascript, node.js, search-engine, express

I want to determine if incoming requests are from a bot (eg google, bing), or a human, and serve different data to each, for example, json data for client javascript to construct the site or preprocessed html.

Using expressjs, is there an easy way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: FYI, search engines tend to not like when they get substantially different content from what a normal client gets.

Comment: @icktoofay it's the same content, if you read google's ajax documentation they expressly allow for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to response according to the requested MIME type (which is present in the "Accept" header). You can do this with Express this way:

```
app.get('/route', function (req, res) {
    if (req.is('json')) res.json(data);
    else if (req.is('html')) res.render('view', {});
    else ...
});
```

Comment: this a better way to deal with requests, great answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can check the req.header('User-Agent') for 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html'. If it's that you know it's Google and can send it different data.

http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=1061943

How to get headers
http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.get

Comment: Thanks yeah, I was doing this, is there no way to generalize across bots, not just target specific bots?

Comment: Each bot has a different user-agent, so you'll have to know what each one is. The accept header may be a better solution. Meaning don't even think about bots, just think about what each 'client' (Browser, JavaScript, Bot) can accept.