# Javascript & Node.js - make a JSON request

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

in this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508758/expressjs-node-js-serve-different-data-to-google-etc-bot-and-human-traffic) I read that in node.js you can distinguish between html requests and json requests like so:

```
app.get('/route', function (req, res) {
    if (req.is('json')) res.json(data);
    else if (req.is('html')) res.render('view', {});
    else ...
});
```

now my question is how do you make a request that is interpreted as json in node server?
cause I tried with $.ajax and $.getJson and typed in the browser and all were html requests.
this is my request

```
$.ajax({ type: 'GET', url: "/test", dataType:"json", success: function(data){log(data)}})
```

Comment: Have you set datatype = json in your ajax call?

Comment: yes I have but didn't make any difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [req.is](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.is) method checks the incoming request type by inspecting the `Content-Type` header therefore you need to make sure this header is set in the request before it's sent up e.g.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/route',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    ....
});
```

However, the [Content-Type](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17) header is used to determine the format of the *request* body, not the response. It's recommended you use the [Accept](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.1) header instead to inform the server of what type of format is appropriate for the response e.g.

```
app.get('/route', function (req, res) {
    if (req.accepts('html')) {
        res.render('view', {});
    } else if (req.accepts('json')) {
        res.json(data);
    } else {
        ...
    }
});
```

Then on the client, you don't need to worry about the `Content-header` but rather the `Accept` header, and jQuery already provides a handy little [method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) for that

```
$.getJSON('/route', function(data) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: thanks that did work, but when I enter the url in the broswer(not $.ajax) it still accepts the request as json, isn't this supposed to be html?

Comment: @user3425760 what you'll probably find is the browser is telling the server it can accept both JSON & HTML responses. You can update your `get` method to prioritise HTML over JSON, I've updated my answer to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `contentType` parameter

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'your_url',
    data: {
        test: "test"
    },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    ....
});
```

**EDIT:**

You can use the **[request Module](https://github.com/mikeal/request)**
all you have to do is

```
var request = require('request');

var options = {
  uri: 'your_server_side_url',
  method: 'POST',
  json: {
    "data": "some_data"
  }
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body.id) // Print the shortened url.
  }
});
```

Check out that github link. May be that module will make your life easier

Comment: I don't need the result in the client, I check how the server is seeing the request.

Comment: first you have to make sure that the ajax request is correctly sent to the server

Comment: the request is sent to server fine, cause I can log the request.

Comment: I'm not getting any error, the request should be in type of "json" but it's always in type of "html" even with the contentType and everything.

Comment: your answer wan't what I was looking for, but you get a vote up anyway